# conditional statements causes syntax errors in python codes

Tags: python, function, anaconda, conditional-statements, statements

```
import traceback

def calculator():
    
    # Get dog age
    age = input("Input dog years: ")

    try:
        # Cast to float
        dage = float(age)
        if dage > 0:
            if dage <= 1:
                print ("The given dog age " + str(dage) + " is " + str(round(dage * 15) ) + " in human years") 
            elif 1 < dage <= 2:
                print ("The given dog age " + str(dage) + " is " + str(round(dage * 12) ) + " in human years")
            elif 2 < dage <= 3 :
                print ("The given dog age " + str(dage) + " is " + str(round(dage * 9.3) ) + " in human years")
            elif 3 < dage <= 4 : 
                print ("The given dog age " + str(dage) + " is " + str(round(dage * 8) ) + " in human years")
            elif 4 < dage <= 5 : 
                print ("The given dog age " + str(dage) + " is " + str(round(dage * 7.2) ) + " in human years")   
            elif 5 < dage : 
                print ("The given dog age " +  str(dage) + " is " + str(36 + 7 * (round(dage - 5.0)) + " in human years")
        else:
             print ("your input should be a positive number")
      except:
        print(age, "is an invalid age.")
        print(traceback.format_exc())
    
calculator() # This line calls the calculator function
```

this code calculates the age of a dog in human years
but when it was executed, there was an error in the 24th line (else:)

Comment: You didn't close print in `elif 5 < dage : `

Comment: You miss a paranthesis at the end of the print after `elif 5 < dage : `

Answer (score 1):

**Solution to your issue**: Your code is missing a closing bracket for `str()` function in the `print` statement for your last `elif`.  Here is the correct statement:

```
elif 5 < dage :
  print ("The given dog age " +  str(dage) + " is " + str(36 + 7 * (round(dage - 5.0))) + " in human years")
```

**Improvements**: You can also use f-strings to improve readability. See [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) for more details. Also, you can simplify the conditions in your elif statements as the lower bound is not needed.

Here is the code using f-strings and with some improvements:

```
def calculator():
    age = input('Input dog years: ')

    try:
        dage = float(age)
        
        if dage > 0:
            msg = f'The given dog age {dage} is '
            if dage <= 1:
                msg += f'{dage * 15:.2f}' 
            elif dage <= 2:
                msg += f'{dage * 12:.2f}'
            elif dage <= 3 :
                msg += f'{dage * 9.3:.2f}'
            elif dage <= 4: 
                msg += f'{dage * 8:.2f}'
            elif dage <= 5 : 
                msg += f'{dage * 7.2:.2f}'
            else: 
                msg += f'{36 + 7 * (dage - 5.0):.2f}'
            msg +=  ' in human years'
            print(msg)
        else:
             print('your input should be a positive number')
    except:
        print(f'{age} is an invalid age.')

calculator()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing parenthesis in

```
elif 5 < dage : 
            print("The given dog age " +  str(dage) + " is " + str(36 + 7 * (round(dage - 5.0)) + " in human years")
```

Add one more parenthesis at the end of print statement

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a bracket on the last print in the else clause.

This is the correct code:

```
import traceback

def calculator():
    
    # Get dog age
    age = input("Input dog years: ")

    try:
        # Cast to float
        dage = float(age)
        if dage > 0:
            if dage <= 1:
                print ("The given dog age " + str(dage) + " is " + str(round(dage * 15) ) + " in human years") 
            elif 1 < dage <= 2:
                print ("The given dog age " + str(dage) + " is " + str(round(dage * 12) ) + " in human years")
            elif 2 < dage <= 3 :
                print ("The given dog age " + str(dage) + " is " + str(round(dage * 9.3) ) + " in human years")
            elif 3 < dage <= 4 : 
                print ("The given dog age " + str(dage) + " is " + str(round(dage * 8) ) + " in human years")
            elif 4 < dage <= 5 : 
                print ("The given dog age " + str(dage) + " is " + str(round(dage * 7.2) ) + " in human years")   
            elif 5 < dage : 
                print ("The given dog age " +  str(dage) + " is " + str(36 + 7 * (round(dage - 5.0)) + " in human years"))
        else:
            print ("your input should be a positive number")
    except:
        print(age, "is an invalid age.")
        print(traceback.format_exc())
    
calculator() # This line calls the calculator function
```